# Two tags for Mahabharata?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There are two tags for Mahabharata [mahabharata](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mahabharata) and [mahabharatha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mahabharatha) (*only one post*). Please suggest whether we should merge the posts related to these tags or make them synonyms to each other. I am also not sure which sounds correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct one is Mahabharata and only one question was tagged with <s>[mahabharatha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mahabharatha)</s> and now I've edited it with the real tag, daily cron job will get rid of the invalid tag.

Comment: Do you have authority to create/Delete tags? If yes then please add tags with some sort of descriptions.

Comment: @TheDictator Sorry?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english
:D

Comment: @TheDictator yes I do have but I won't make, its like, we can make 10000 tags, so let the user create tags when they ask questions if they don't find any, if there are synonyms or useless tags, post a question on meta and I'll take care of them

Comment: But atleast we can make some of the popular ones like Mahabharata,Ramayana,shiv,krishna,vishnu,etc... so in suggestions it will come with their Some sort of description. As many times i have seens that mostly south indian users to that they are adding additional "h" or "t" in each and every word. So this will prevent from this kind of Mistakes.

Comment: @TheDictator I am not a professional so I won't be editing wiki tags, it would be better if users with accurate knowledge edit them out.

Comment: You can take help of other mods as well as jabahar and other leading users as they are masters in this. Its just an opinion. Rest is upto you.

Comment: @TheDictator Site is just started, wait for some time, users like Ankit, Dharmaputhiran etc are editing wiki tags, will raise a question on meta soon if I don't see major tags edited :)